# Lucene search match any word at phrase

Tags: java, solr, lucene, search-engine

i wanna search a string with lots of words, and retrieves documents that matches with any of them. My indexing method is the folowing:

```
 Document document = new Document();
 document.add(new TextField("termos", text, Field.Store.YES));
 document.add(new TextField("docNumber",fileNumber,Field.Store.YES));

 config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
 Analyzer analyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
            .withTokenizer("standard")
            .addTokenFilter("lowercase")
            .addTokenFilter("stop")
            .addTokenFilter("porterstem")
            .addTokenFilter("capitalization")
            .build();
 config = IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
 writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, config);
 writer.addDocument(document);
 writer.commit();
```

And here is my search method. I dont wanna look for specific phrase, but any of word in that. The analyzer for search is the same that for index.

```
Query query = new QueryBuilder(analyzer).createPhraseQuery("termos","THE_PHRASE");
String indexDir = rootProjectFolder + "/indexDir/";
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(1000,1000);
searcher.search(query,collector);
```

Im new on Lucene. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `createPhraseQuery("termos", "list of words")` will precisely try to match the phrase "list of words" with a phrase slop of 0.

If you want to match *any* term in a list of words, you can use [`createBooleanQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/util/QueryBuilder.html#createBooleanQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause.Occur-) :

```
new QueryBuilder(analyzer).createBooleanQuery("termos", terms, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

As an alternative, you can also use [`createMinShouldMatchQuery()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/util/QueryBuilder.html#createMinShouldMatchQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-float-) so that you can require a fraction of the number of query terms to match, eg. to match at least 10 percent of the terms :

```
new QueryBuilder(analyzer).createMinShouldMatchQuery("termos", terms, 0.1f));
```